# CPack filelist conflicts with filesystem

Tags: packaging, cpack

I try to package my project written in C++ and using cmake as a build tool. I can create a rpm package but I can not install it. The error message is:

```
file /usr/local from install of myapp.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.3-3.fc27.x86_64
file /usr/local/include from install of myapp.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.3-3.fc27.x86_64
file /usr/local/bin from install of myapp.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.3-3.fc27.x86_64
file /usr/local/etc from install of myapp.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.3-3.fc27.x86_64
```

I tried to set `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION` in `CMakeList.txt` but it is not work.

```
set(CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION /usr/local /usr/local/etc /usr/local/bin /usr/local/include`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on my C++ project, and for that sake, when tried to install the generated RPM on CentOS, yum raises conflict errors with the existing files or directories (/usr/bin dir for example).

So, after take a look at CPackRPM documentation (I'm using cmake 3.10.2-1 at Debian Testing), I've realized that for `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST` option, already exists a default list that already includes: `/etc; /etc/init.d /usr; /usr/bin; /usr/include; /usr/lib; /usr/libx32; /usr/lib64; /usr/share; /usr/share/aclocal; /usr/share/doc`.

What I was actually doing was to override with the same options. Not sure if cpack gets lost or something like this, but after REMOVE my own `set(CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST)` from my `CMakeLists.txt` and leave it default, worked well.

I just deleted the build dir, ran `cmake` again and `cpack -G RPM` and everything worked fine. Just check the new RPM generated file with `rpm -qpl yourpackage.rpm` and see if its OK.

And if you realy need a list of excluded files, try to use the  `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION` instead.

Answer (score 0):

setting something like this should fix the issue:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_DEFAULT_DIR_PERMISSIONS
    OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE
    GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
    WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
```

the reason behind is permission, that directories are owned by `filesystem.rpm` pacakge that set permissions to `0755` most likely your rpm package on those permissions are `0775` as a for Debian defaults.

you can check your rpm permissions with the following command:

```bash
rpm -q --queryformat="[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILEUSERNAME}:%{FILEGROUPNAME} %{FILENAMES}\n]" myapp
```

and looks at your directory listed from the result of the rpm query of the above command, for e.g. `/usr/local`, to have permissions like (`0755`):
:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root local
```

---

in fact you can also double check against `filesystem` itself with:

```
rpm -q --queryformat="[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILEUSERNAME}:%{FILEGROUPNAME} %{FILENAMES}\n]" filesystem
```

and you will see the `/usr/local/` as:

```
drwxr-xr-x root:root /usr/local
```